# Delay the response by some seconds when scraping a website

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am working on a php scraping server , so i have website list to loop and then return the content of each page to get the data that i want.

The problem that some sites are not fully returned and as i see some data appear after the page is fully loaded

I tried with both these methods but i cant get the full page

First method :

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'timeout' => 10 
    ) );

$context  = stream_context_create($opts); 
$html = file_get_contents('some url',false,$context);  
echo $html;
```

Second method

```
$html = implode('',file('some url')); 
echo $html;
```

I just want to return the content of the page after 1 or 2 seconds after the page is loaded.

For Exemple with this [url](http://www.eonline.com/search?query=test) i cant get the search results just this

> : Résultats
>    News Photos Vidéos Tags Filtre par date
>    Précédente Suivante

Comment: This is usually the result of results that are loaded through JavaScript. You need to scrape via something that can run JavaScript like PhantomJS or Chrome in headless mode.

Comment: You are saying your script is only getting partial html from the urls you hit? I've not run into that before, it usually gets all or nothing in my use. Odd. Have you tried curl grabbing? It has more settings you can toy with.

Comment: @Randall yes it dont return the full page , i was just trying with curl and it appear to be the same

Comment: @apokryfos i will try with PhantomJS

Answer (score 0):

Things are not as they seem to be. 
Actually the url that you want to hit is 
https://api.swiftype.com/api/v1/public/engines/search.json because the webpage on load makes a json request that is on this url.
in that url you have to post the following json

```
$search = array("engine_key"=>"naxCjQ58frTkB_diETvu","page"=>1,"q"=>"kardas","per_page"=>12,"sort_direction"=>"","filters"=>array("page"=>array("category"=>"News")),"facets"=>array("page"=>array("0"=>"tag")));
```

A quick guide:

1. On the "page" property type a value, that represents the page number you want to get,
2. on the "q" property type the term that you want to search,
3. "per_page" property is the entries that you will get, try some
   values, 12 is the default,
4. the rest you have to find them out yourself.

a code example that works

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.swiftype.com/api/v1/public/engines/search.json");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($search));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

and to check the results

```
print_r(json_decode($data));
```

this thing is beautiful is like them to give you an API on the plate...